# Add Date to Oracle Database type Date

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime

I want to add a date to database. But only the date without time.

If I have a variable type **DateTime** it works but inserts with time **00:00:00.**

I tried this but it keep gives me input error.

```
INSERT INTO BNR(EUR,DATE_API) VALUES ( 4.2546 , to_date('2016/30/03','DD-MON-YY') );
```

This is my date variable

```
  DateTime date_bnr = (from cube in doc.Descendants(d + "Cube")
                        from rate in cube.Elements(d + "Rate")
                        where
                          ((DateTime)cube.Attribute("date")).Date == yesterday
                              &&
                          (string)rate.Attribute("currency") == "EUR"
                        select ((DateTime)cube.Attribute("date")).Date 
       ).FirstOrDefault();

 var datebnr = date_bnr.ToShortDateString();   // what I tried
 var dt = date_bnr.ToString("DD-MON-YY");      // what I tried
```

And this is my Insert to Database

```
 string insert_bnr = "INSERT INTO BNR(EUR,DATE_API) VALUES (:value,:datee) ";
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(insert_bnr, con);

            OracleParameter bnr_value = new OracleParameter();
            bnr_value.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
            bnr_value.Value = bnr.ToString();

            OracleParameter bnr_date = new OracleParameter();
            bnr_date.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date;
            bnr_date.Value = dt;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(bnr_value);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(bnr_date);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Oracle dates always have a time, even if it's midnight. Whether you display that is another matter. With `to_date('2016/30/03','DD-MON-YY')`, why are you using a format mask that doesn't match the string literal you have? What does `ToShortDateString()` produce? And why are you setting that parameter as a string rather than a date?

Comment: "2016/30/03" does not match the format string "DD-MON-YY", what is "input error"? do you get an exception, if yes, which?

Comment: The error is "SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string" and ToShortDateString() it gives me only the date without date

Comment: And that error is because '2016/30/03' is in format 'YYYY/DD/MM' (really?) not 'DD-MON-YY'. If you're going to pass that value as a string then include a `to_date()` in the insert statement with a *matching* format mask. Or pass it as an actual date, rather than converting to a string for the call and then converting back to a date for the insert.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `check` constraint to validate that the input has no time component:

```
alter table bnr add constraint chk_date_api check (date_api = trunc(date_api));
```

This will make sure there is no time component in the column in the table.  But, it returns an error if an `update` or `insert` sets a date with a value.  Hence, it is up to the application to insert correct data to avoid the error.

Another alternative is to use a trigger to remove any time component.  Personally, I think that is overkill if you have the `check` constraint.

Comment: The OP seems to already be inserting with the time set to midnight, but wants a data type that has no time at all (I think). Which doesn't exist, of course. This is useful to ensure a different time isn't set by accident, but I'm not sure that's really what was being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Format `to_date('2016/30/03','DD-MON-YY')` does not match.

It must be either `to_date('03/MARCH/16','DD-MON-YY')` or (preferably) `to_date('2016/30/03','YYYY/DD/MM')`